# Won't start up grub 2.2 beta start up mode want it to start up normally

Tags: grub2, startup

One moment you I'm watching Netflix then my computer starts lagging then chrome keeps shutting down then the computer restarted. Then goes into gnu grub 2.2  beta now it's

```
/dev/sda1 contra file system with errors, check forced. 
/dev/sda1: Unexpected inconsistency; run fsck manually.
(I.e., without -a or -p options)
Back with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual face
Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) enter help for list of commands

(Initramfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Was told on Ubuntu Forums to run manually
run fsck manually

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333655